# i need multiple input to run main function phonebook python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I am having trouble writing a program to repeat input part. for instance

```
input 1 ___run add_contact()
again ask for input
input 4____run disp_contact()
...
...
```

I've never written a long code! :\

I'm totally begginer! and learning a bit of Python in my spare time
my mentor said you should define several functions and put them in a main function which get input.
so If anyone can tell me why I get stuck like this I would appreciate it.

```
contact={}
print(''' phone book
    1. add contact
    2.delete contact
    3.search contact
    4.display all
    5.Quit''')

def add_contact():
    name=input('enter the name: ')
    number=input('enter the number: ')
    contact[name]=number
    print(name, 'added to phone book!')
    
def del_contact():
    name=input('enter the name: ')
   
    while name not in contact:
        print("not found! try again" )
        name=input('enter again: ')

    else:    
        print(name,' deleted')
        del contact[name]
        name=False
      
        
        
def search_contact():
    name=input('enter the name: ')
    while name not in contact:
        print('not found!')
        name=input('enter again: ')  
    else:
        print(name, 'number is :',  contact[name])  
        
def disp_contact():
    if len(contact)>0:
       print('phone book contacts are: ')
       for i in contact:
         print(i, end=' ')
    else:
      print('phone book is empty!')    
    
        
def main_def(num):
       

       if num==1:
              add_contact()
              
       elif num==2:
              del_contact()
              
       elif num==3:
              search_contact()
              
       elif num==4:
              disp_contact()

       elif num==5:
          print('bye bye') 



x=int(input(' enter a number: '))
main_def(x)
```

Comment: You may think about [accepting an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to reward those how helped you, or at least comment to explain what's missing ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may wrap the `main_def` in a `while True`, and use `exit(O)` to quit properly when `5` is given

```
def main_def(num):
    if num == 1:
        add_contact()
    elif num == 2:
        del_contact()
    elif num == 3:
        search_contact()
    elif num == 4:
        disp_contact()
    elif num == 5:
        exit(0)

while True:
    x = int(input(' enter a number: '))
    main_def(x)
```

---

#### Note

For `del_contact` and `search_contact`, you don't need the `else` just put after like this

```
def del_contact():
    name = input('enter the name: ')

    while name not in contact:
        print("not found! try again")
        name = input('enter again: ')

    print(name, ' deleted')
    del contact[name]
```

Comment: TNX a lot but  elif num == 5: exit(0) not worked! ;(

Comment: @GhazalKz what do you mean by "not worked" ?

Comment: stop the function!

Comment: @GhazalKz i ´ve tried and it worked well, `exit` does stop the program for sure, but you can keep you print that said ByeBye juste before the exit, do you think it doesn’t stop because it doesn’t tell you it stopped ?

Comment: I think something was wrong with my IDE.sorry.

Comment: @GhazalKz you can think about accepting the answer so ;)